# Why do my two sites targeted at the same keywords never appear in the Google search result together?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, keywords, multiple-domains

I have two sites now, and had been doing Google SEO working about 6 months.

- One site appeared on the 1st page of google search result of target keywords.
- The other site also appeared for some keywords.

Then, I worked targeting the same keywords for the two sites.

My sites never appear together even one time on the 1st page of the Google search results. When the 1st site appears on the 1st page, 2nd site is on the 5~7th page, or otherwise happens. Why?

I started and opened the two site at almost same time. The 1st site is made on Wix, the 2nd on Wordpress.
The contents are not the same.  Each site is absolutely unique, but the target keywords are almost same.
Backlinks have some of the same sources, but I don't think this is the reason.

Comment: "or otherwise happens" - are you saying they effectively switch places in the search results for the same search phrase? ie. 2nd site on 1st page and 1st site on 5~7th page? There's no cross-linking between the sites?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Of course, there are no links between two sites. Ever there was one link from 1st site to 2nd site. But after about 2 months, I eliminated it.